# Numpad enter key stopped working?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, numpad

Dell inspiron 15R's numpad Enter key suddently stopped working !
The keyboard layout is the same, I don't think something changed !

Any ideas ?

Comment: If you run the on-screen keyboard `onboard`, does the corresponding Enter key work?

Comment: @sudodus, Running `onboard` and clikcing on Num, resulting in a working **onscreen** enter key, but still the keyboard one doesn't work.

Comment: I'm trying to help you find out if it is a hardware or software problem. What happens if you boot the computer live, 'Try Ubuntu' from a USB drive or a DVD disk?

Comment: @sudodus, OK, Tried with a dualboot Windows 10, and seems not working as well !. I think that means it is a hardware problem then ?

Comment: Yes, I am afraid it is a hardware problem. If you must use the numpad a lot and at home, maybe it would work with a separate keyboard.

Comment: @sudodus, The point is it almost happened when I began to use Windows 10 as dualboot, before that, was working great with Ubuntu !

Comment: If I understand correctly, the computer is several years old. I found this review from June 2010, https://www.cnet.com/products/dell-inspiron-15r/review/2/ Even if the keys will usually work until the computer is recycled, they might fail after several years. Of course, you can try with another linux distro (try it live).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We *think* we have found that this is a hardware problem. The following tips might be useful for other users with similar problems, in order to find out, if it is a hardware or software problem.

1. If you run the on-screen keyboard *onboard*, does the corresponding key work?

   ```
   onboard
   ```

   If not installed install with

   ```
   sudo apt-get install onboard
   ```
2. If you boot the computer live, 'Try Ubuntu' from a USB drive or a DVD disk? Does that key work? Or try live with another linux distro.
3. If you dual boot with another operating system, for example Windows, does that key work in the other operating system?