# The main enter key stopped working but the numpad one works fine

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, kde

While I was using my Ubuntu installation (I use kde as my desktop environment if that matters) my keyboard disconnected then connected again suddenly then my main enter key stopped working on both the laptop keyboard and the external keyboard, however the numpad <kbd>enter</kbd> key works just fine.

Both <kbd>enter</kbd> keys work just fine on windows.

Also my keyboard disconnecting and connecting again automatically is something I'm used to since I'm using a shitty dongle.

I've tried connecting the keyboard without the dongle.

I'm running out of ideas anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: as this answer suggests: https://askubuntu.com/a/867391/366957 have you tried an on screen keyboard? does it work on that? (just to rule out a hardware related error)

Comment: Check with `xev` (package _x11-utils_) what key codes both keys send.

Comment: that thread doesn't help my case since I'm sure it is a software issue since i tried other keyboard and my keyboard works fine on windows.
as for xev this is what it returns when i press the numpad enter (the one that works) :
https://ibb.co/VJqQ8jJ
and this is what it returns when i press the none working default enter key in the middle of the keyboard :
https://ibb.co/VNkW4xW

Comment: have you tried to add another keyboard layout to see if the key works there and then back to your layout?

Comment: sadly it doesn't work in all layouts including the ones that use none latin characters.